# Printing an ASP.NET Web Site page

Tags: asp.net

I have spent 5 days researching how to print a DataList in a C# Visual Studio WEB SITE.  I can print the DataList in a Web Project.  It appears that since a Site does not have "namespace" as does a Project, Microsoft just didn't bother making a Web Site page printable.  I have a rather large Web Site almost developed, and now it appears a major function of a Site is not possible.  I need help!  Thanks in advance.

P.S.  It would seem that Microsoft would have mentioned this little problem in their literature comparing a Project to a Site, but they didn't.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeBehind="PageLinkDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDataBase.PageLinkDetails" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Caribbean %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CaribbeanDirections] WHERE ([RecipeID] = @RecipeID)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="RecipeID" QueryStringField="RecipeID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="DirectionID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
                INGREDIENTS:<br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientOneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientOne") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientTwoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientTwo") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientThreeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientThree") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientFourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientFour") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientFiveLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientFive") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientSixLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientSix") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientSevenLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientSeven") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientEightLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientEight") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientNineLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientNine") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientTenLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IngredientTen") %>' />
                <br />
                Directions:<br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionOneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DirectionOne") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionTwoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DirectionTwo") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionThreeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DirectionThree") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionFourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DirectionFour") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrintCurrent" runat="server" Text="Print Current Page" OnClick="PrintCurrentPage" />
   </div>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("RecipeID",      "PageLinkDetails.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>'
    Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>Rate This Recipe</asp:HyperLink>
  </asp:Content>



using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
 using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace TestDataBase
{
public partial class PageLinkDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        BindGrid();
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string strQuery = "select * " + "from CaribbeanDirections";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["Caribbean"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            //*DataList1.DataSource = dt;
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /*Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }

    protected void OnPaging(object sender, PageEventArgs e)
    {

        DataList1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void PrintCurrentPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DataList1.DataBind();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        DataList1.RenderControl(hw);
        string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
            .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
        sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
        sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
        sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
        sb.Append(gridHTML);
        sb.Append("\");");
        sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
        sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
        sb.Append("printWin.print();");
        sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());

        DataList1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ctrl"] = pnl1;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to print the entire page? or Just a Datalist that is part of page?

Comment: Can you post the code that works in Project?

Comment: You can probably make it work, but I suggest never using Web Site "projects". They are very strange in many ways.

Comment: I just want to print the data returned by the DataList.  The code I put in the edit above works fine.  It is in a Project.  Transferring the same code to a Site will not work.  I have tried using DIV, javascript, you name it.  The page does appear to postback but a print page will not come up, even with popup code.

Comment: @John Saunders, I'm not using a "project". That perhaps is the problem. I can get the page to work in a project, but it will not work in a "Site", which I am using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print only a Datalist from a webpage. You can create a Div Name around the datalist and use the below code

```
<script language="javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

Give a div name around the Datalist like this.

```
<div id="PrintDiv">
       <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">     </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Finally Create a print button.

```
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('PrintDiv')" value="Print only Datalist!" />
```

**EDIT**

Your exact code worked for me. I created a ASP.NET website (Not Project). I copied your entire code 
and pasted into a new page and it worked.

The only thing I changed is the following.

I changed `CodeBehind="PageLinkDetails.aspx.cs"` to `CodeFile="PageLinkDetails.aspx.cs"`

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeFile="PageLinkDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDataBase.PageLinkDetails" %>
```

**EDIT**

Here is my Complete Code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeFile="PageLinkDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestDataBase.PageLinkDetails" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
        <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>"

            SelectCommand="SELECT first AS Name, uid AS Id FROM users WHERE (uid IN (250, 251, 253, 252, 254))">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
                INGREDIENTS:<br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientOneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientTwoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientThreeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientFourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientFiveLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientSixLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientSevenLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientEightLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientNineLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="IngredientTenLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                Directions:<br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionOneLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionTwoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionThreeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="DirectionFourLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                <br />
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnPrintCurrent" runat="server" Text="Print Current Page" OnClick="PrintCurrentPage" />
   </div>
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("Id",      "PageLinkDetails.aspx?RecipeId={0}") %>'
    Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>Rate This Recipe</asp:HyperLink>
  </asp:Content>
```

This is code for aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace TestDataBase
{
    public partial class PageLinkDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            BindGrid();
        }

        private void BindGrid()
        {
            string strQuery = "SELECT first AS Name, uid AS Id FROM users WHERE (uid IN (250, 251, 253, 252, 254))";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                        .ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                //*DataList1.DataSource = dt;
                DataList1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                sda.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /*Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }

        protected void OnPaging(object sender, PageEventArgs e)
        {

            DataList1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void PrintCurrentPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DataList1.DataBind();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            DataList1.RenderControl(hw);
            string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
                .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
            sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
            sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
            sb.Append(gridHTML);
            sb.Append("\");");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
            sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
            sb.Append("printWin.print();");
            sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());

            DataList1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["ctrl"] = pnl1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With all due respect, that will not work in a Web Site.  It may in a Web Project.

Comment: The results of `Web Project` and `Web Site` are `HTML`,the answer is pure `Java Script` , you use it without any problem!

Comment: Sorry, but that is not correct either.  I've used javascript also.  Doesn't work.  See the .cs above.  That is very close to javascript.  Rework into function and it still will not work.

Comment: Cherian, I setup two pages, one in a web project and one in a web site with identical code, using your suggested code.  The web project print worked like a charm.  The web site would not print.  No popup/print window came up in the Site but it did in the Project.  Which goes back to my original problem: Can a web site page be printed?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Web Developer 2010.  From the very limited discussion I can find on the net, it appears that the difference between Project and Site is that the Project uses  "namespace" in the .cs code behind and the Site does not.  Your code works in conjunction with the "namespace" but does not if the code behind does not have "namespace".  I have also tried "importing" namespace into the Site, but that does not work either.

Comment: I have updated my answer! Check the Edit part.. It works with "CodeFile" not "CodeBehid"

Comment: Cherian, I do appreciate your help.  I think I did exactly as you said and it still isn't working.  Did you copy/use the .cs code behind or did you use your previously given print code?  I have done both, used your code and also used what I was using with the project. When I copied the code from "project" into "site", I had to change the "namespace" name, but the "codefile" was already changed, I did not have to change it from "codebehind" - since it was a site instead of a project, I assume. Could you possibly post your entire code so I can compare to what I have done?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in my website and it worked... I have edited the answer to show the code that worked. Check it out!

Comment: Cherian, thank you, you did it.  You have done something most on the net have not been able to address.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a very late answer, but for the new users who might come to this post like me, I want them to know that they can easily print the page using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (PRINT COMMAND). To print just a few elements you can add the classname or id. Have a look as below:

#### Printing the page

To print the page, simply press the Print Command on any browser. Or simply use the JS command

```
window.print();
```

You can keep this inside an event or anyother thing that you might want to be used such as a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Print" id="print" onclick="print()" />

function print() {
  window.print();
}
```

#### Printing only a part

Now that we have CSS3 in our hand, we can easily snip out the part we want to be printed. Here is example:

```
@media print {
   /* properties for printed page */
}
```

Any of the property you declare here would be applied to the document while its in hard copy (printed form). If you want to hide the footer or other divs, you can set them to invisible as

```
@media print {
  footer, header, non-printable-part {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Now, when you send the print command or click the button. You're gonna see only the printable part. It has been made easy using CSS3 Media Query.